# How to fit frame to content for text boxes in Photoshop similar to InDesign?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, text

Is there a way to fit frame to content for text boxes in photoshop like they have that feature in indesign? because sometimes when the text frame is larger than the text with empty space, and we try to align objects, it's not accurate.

would like to know if there is a way to do this in photoshop without manually dragging the text box because there may be room for error as opposed to the feature indesign has which just automatically fits frame to content for the text box.

Comment: It'd be nice if you'd add some images explaining what you want for people not familiar with ID

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that in Photoshop.